# Obtain a list from 2 lists of strings

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

For these lists:

```
a=['applepearstrawberry','applepearbanana','orangekiwiapple','xxxxxxxxxxx']
b=['apple','pear']
```

How do you return a list with any elements that contain 'apple' or 'pear'.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
c=['applepearstrawberry','applepearbanana','orangekiwiapple']
```

Attempted solution:

```
c=[]
for i in a:
    if b[0] or b[1] in a:
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

Thankyou

Comment: Your code is fine, except that you need to check `b[0] in a or b[1] in a`. `b[0] or b[1] in a` will almost always be `True`. Does this answer your question? [Why does \`a == x or y or z\` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```py
a = ["applepearstrawberry", "applepearbanana", "orangekiwiapple", "xxxxxxxxxxx"]
b = ["apple", "pear"]

out = [v for v in a if any(w in v for w in b)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['applepearstrawberry', 'applepearbanana', 'orangekiwiapple']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `if b[0] or b[1] in a:` contains a common mistake. Python interprets this line as `if (b[0]) or (b[1] in a):`, which will be true anytime `b[0]` is not empty.

You could fix this by using `if b[0] in a or b[1] in a:`. But if `b` might not have two values, you're better off using one of these:

```
if any(w in a for w in b):
```

or

```
for w in b:
    if w in a:
        c.append(w)
        break
```

Or, for a simple one-liner based on `any`, see [Andrej Kesely's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68168594/3830997).

Comment: Ahh great - thanks for the learnings.